# Gatling SOCKS proxy

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I'm setting socks5 proxy in Gatling script like this

```
http("request1")
.post("https://myurl.com")
.proxy(Proxy("localhost", 7777).socks5)
```

but in the log it shows as HttpProxyServer instead of Socks5ProxyServer

```
proxy=HttpProxyServer{realm=null, securedPort=7777, securedAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1:7777, host='localhost', port=7777}
```

and my requests timeout

i verified socks proxy is working via curl, also it works in jmeter using  `-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -DsocksProxyPort=7777`

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed now: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3777 , Thanks Stephane!

I verified it works now after building Gatling from source*

i can see correct proxy now as well, and request goes through

```
proxy=Socks5ProxyServer{realm=null, host='localhost', port=7777}
```

*Note: **to build gatling from source** you need to build 3 projects (I wish this was part of documentation):

```
    1) git clone git@github.com:gatling/gatling.git

      update gatling/version.sbt to e.g. 3.2.1-SNAPSHOT

      cd gatling; sbt publishM2; cd ../  

    2) git clone git@github.com:gatling/gatling-highcharts.git

       update gatling-highcharts/version.sbt to e.g. 3.2.1-SNAPSHOT

       cd gatling-highcharts; sbt publishM2; cd ../  

    3) git clone git@github.com:gatling/gatling-highcharts-maven-archetype.git  

      update version in gatling-highcharts-maven-archetype/pom.xml to e.g. 3.2.1-SNAPSHOT

      cd gatling-highcharts-maven-archetype; mvn clean install; 

      cd  target/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.2.1-SNAPSHOT
       bin/gatling.sh
```